# Javascript/jQuery Dropdown menu update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdown menus - when I select an option on the first I want the other to change to its corresponding option based on its matching value. I am currently using this JS code:

```
document.getElementById("select_1").onchange = function() {
        console.log("select_1", this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
        document.getElementById("select_75").value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
    };
```

However the end result does not change/update correctly unless I change manually the second (select_75) dropdown to another option and then back to the changed option (set by select_1).

Are there any changes I could make to the code or other setup entirely to try out in order make this happen? Open to using jQuery as well.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/74a4uqh4/

Comment: why are you not using jquery?

Comment: Using a wordpress based website. A lot of other coding as well which I guess causes this. So simply looking for other methods of doing the same thing hoping for better result. Maybe to add code which updates select_75 or changes it an extra time before getting to value of select_1?

Comment: Do you have any recommendations @ParvSharma to do it with jquery?

Comment: Tried this code as well, did not work:

Comment: `document.getElementById("select_1").onchange=function() {
     document.getElementById("select_75").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value"); 
  }
  document.getElementById("select_1").onchange();`